# Compute $P(C)$ given that $P(C|A ∩ B) = 0.75$ and $P(C|A' ∩ B) = 0.5$

Tags: probability

Let $A$ and $B$ be independent events.

Let $P(A) = 0.8, P(B) = 0.8$ and $C ⊂ B$. Given that $P(C|A ∩ B) = 0.75$ and
$P(C|A' ∩ B) = 0.5$, compute $P(C)$.

I don't know how to do this without assuming and all 3 A, B and C are mutually independent. Can I assume this? If not, how else do I do this question?

Comment: $A,B,C$ are not mutually independent, as that would require $0.75=0.5$

Comment: Since $C ⊂ B$, you can say $P(C\mid B') =0$

Comment: Since $A$ and $B$ are independent events, you can say $P(A\mid B) =P(A\mid B') =P(A) =0.8$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that 
$$P(C) = P(AC)+P(A'C).\tag 1$$

Also,
$$P(C|AB) = \frac{P(ABC)}{P(AB)} =\frac{P(AC)}{P(AB)} = .75\tag 2$$
and
$$P(C|A'B) = \frac{P(A'C)}{P(A'B)} = .5\tag 3$$

Then using $(2)$ and $(3)$, we have
\begin{align*}
P(C)&=P(AC)+P(A'C) \\
&= .75P(AB)+.5P(A'B) \\
&= .75P(A)P(B)+.5[P(B)-P(A)P(B)]\tag 4 \\
&= .75(.8)(.8)+.5[.8-.8(.8)]\\
&= 0.56
\end{align*}
where in $(4)$ I used $P(B) = P(AB)+P(A'B)$.